# How to rewrite my url parameter with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have the following url:

```
http://example.com/folder/index.php?module=centrale&DIO0=1
```

I need this page to be availeble with the following URL format:

```
http://example.com/folder/centrale/?DIO0=1
```

But how do i rewrite this using htaccess properly? What i've got so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^centrale/(.*)$ /index.php?module=centrale ????? $1
```

Notice that the `DIO0` parameter is not always the only one, so the query string must be completly passed trough. Thanks in advance for helping me out or setting me in the right direction.

Edit: the htaccess file is located here: `http://example.com/folder/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^centrale/$ index.php?module=centrale [L,QSA]
```

the [QSA] flag (Query String Append) will add the rest of the parameters automatically